# Declared variable not showing up in Locals of Debugger

Tags: c

This is a simple program to calculate the length of lines. All the calculation aspects of the program are done and working.
But I am having trouble on one very simple aspect, the variable "percent_detoured" is declared on line 10 and used on line 83, and printed on line 84. Problem is when executed, everything else runs fine but percent_detoured consistently returns 0.000. When debugged, percent_detoured does not even show as a variable in "Locals". 
I am using Pelles C IDE if that helps.

Thanks for the help!

```
{
float line_value;       
int x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2;         
float y_intercept;      
float distance, greatest_distance, total;
float percent_detoured;             // <-- DECLARED HERE (SCROLL ALL THE WAY DOWN TO SEE WHERE IT IS USED)
int count, detour_count;        

x_1=1; y_1=1; x_2=1; y_2=1;     
greatest_distance = 0;  total = 0;  count = 0;  detour_count = 0; 

/* Ask for user input in setting the coordinates of the line */
printf("Enter in the length of the line\n");
scanf("%f", &line_value);


/* If user enters in y coordinates for the line such that the line length is greater
    than 10 units, then enter loop and continue looping until the length is smaller or 
    equal to 10 */
while ( line_value > 10 || line_value < 0)
{
    printf("Try Again. Value should be smaller or equal to 10 units\n");
    scanf("%f", &line_value);
}

line_value = line_value / 2;            //Define the top of the line

printf("Enter x and y coordinates for point 1 and 2\n");
scanf("%d %d %d %d", &x_1, &y_1, &x_2, &y_2);

if ( x_1 == 0 && x_2 == 0 && y_1 == 0 && y_2 == 0 )     //If user enters in 0 0 0 0 right away, then immediately end the program
{
    printf("No path lengths have been calculated\n");
}

else        
{
    /* While the user does not enter in the values 0 0 0 0 for all coordinates, continue while loop */
    while ( (x_1 != 0) || (y_1 != 0) || (x_2 != 0) || (y_2 != 0) )
    {
        y_intercept = y_1 - ( (y_2 - y_1) / (x_2 - x_1) * x_1 );    //Rearrange (y=mx+b) to get (b=y-mx) where b is the y intercept

        if ( y_intercept <= line_value && y_intercept >= 0 )    //If the y-intercept of the line from point a to b is between
        {                                                           //the top of L and 0, then calculate distance between a and top of L
            distance = sqrt( pow(x_1, 2) + pow((y_1 - line_value), 2) )
                        + sqrt( pow(x_2, 2) + pow((line_value - y_2), 2) );
            detour_count++;                 //Updating the detour counter
        }
        else if ( y_intercept >= ( line_value * -1) && y_intercept < 0 )    //If the y-intercept of the line from point a to b is between 
        {                                                                   //the bottom of L and 0, then calculate distance between a and bottom of L
            distance = sqrt( pow(x_1, 2) + pow( (y_1 + line_value), 2) )
                        + sqrt( pow(x_2, 2) + pow(( y_2 - (line_value * -1) ), 2) );
            detour_count++;                 //Updating the detour counter
        }
        else 
        {
            distance = sqrt( pow((x_2 - x_1), 2) + pow((y_2 - y_1), 2));    //If shortest path between point a and b does not cross L,
        }                                                                   //then the distance is just the sum of squares of rise and run

        if (distance > greatest_distance)
        {
            greatest_distance = distance;   //If the current distance is greater than the previous, set it as the greatest distance
        }

        total = total + distance;       //Total count of distance
        count++;                        //Update general counter

        printf("The shortest path is: %f\n", distance);

        printf("Enter x and y coordinates for point 1 and 2\n");
        scanf("%d %d %d %d", &x_1, &y_1, &x_2, &y_2);
    }

}

printf("\nThe average path length: %f\n", (total/count));       
printf("The length of the longest path: %f\n", greatest_distance);

percent_detoured = ((detour_count/count) * 100);        // <-- USED IT HERE
printf("The percentage of paths involving a detour: %f\n", percent_detoured );    // <-- SHOULD BE PRINTED AS ITS VALUE HERE

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
percent_detoured = ((float)detour_count/count) * 100.0);
```

Else, both detour_count and count are integers, and int divided by int will give an int. So assuming that detour_count < count, detour_count/count will be rounded to 0, multiplied by 100 (still 0) and finally rounded to float since it is being stored as a float (percent_detoured).

I never used the IDE you mentioned, so I have no clue why it might not be showing up in the debugger. :)

Comment: Thank You, i understand it now. The variable still does not show in debug but that's ok!